# Execute a trigger on a view in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, view, triggers, hsqldb

I am not too familiar with database triggers and/or views. I am currently using PostgreSQL and HSQL, even though the database is not too important. I am just wondering if *any* database offers something like this:

I have an (example) table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DUMMY_TABLE (ID INTEGER, NUMBER INTEGER);
```

I created a view like this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW DUMMY_VIEW AS SELECT * FROM DUMMY_TABLE WHERE NUMBER > 5;
```

I insert a couple of entities:

```sql
INSERT INTO DUMMY_TABLE VALUES(1,2);
INSERT INTO DUMMY_TABLE VALUES(1,10);
```

So of course, the `DUMMY_VIEW` only contains `VALUES(1,10)` when I call:

```sql
SELECT * FROM DUMMY_VIEW;
```

So now what I want to do is add a trigger to the `DUMMY_VIEW` that is called whenever an entity is inserted that has `NUMBER > 5`.

I have tried adding triggers directly to the `DUMMY_VIEW` in both HSQL and PostgreSQL but they say that triggers cannot be added to views.

Is this (or a functionally similar solution) possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It should be noted that PostgreSQL 9.1+ supports triggers on views. See [WAITING FOR 9.1 – TRIGGERS ON VIEWS](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/10/16/waiting-for-9-1-triggers-on-views/) for a brief look at this.

Comment: triggers on views are instead of triggers and are used only to make updatable views. They will not solve the problem from the question, as they are not listening on the changes to underlying tables

Comment: when the data on an underlying tables changes then the view changes thats how they work.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, triggers cannot be placed on views directly. What you should do is place a trigger on the base table and check to see if the new NUMBER row has a value greater than 5.

Note: a view is only a stored select statement, so it does not really hold data. That is why one cannot check to see whether data is being inserted, deleted or updated in a view structure.

Comment: in oracle you can place triggers on views

Comment: As of postgresql 9.1, you can use triggers on views.

Comment: @JoeVanDyk copy pasting marcin's comment: triggers on views are instead of triggers and are used only to make updatable views. They will not solve the problem from the question, as they are not listening on the changes to underlying tables

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to put the trigger on the table, not the view.

The trigger could use a query on the view so that you are [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Is there any other reason the trigger needs to be on the view and not the table?

An example in response to the comment

```
-- Create function
CREATE FUNCTION doWhatIwant() RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
IF NEW.number > 5 THEN
  do_stuff
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Create trigger
CREATE TRIGGER yourTrigger AFTER INSERT ON dummy_table
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE doWhatIwant();
```

Comment: The reason I want the trigger on the view is so that it is ONLY called when the Number of a newly inserted entity is greater than 5.  Is this possible if I add a trigger to the table itself?  This is all very unfamiliar to me.

Comment: With HSQLDB, when you define the trigger on a table, the trigger code can have a condition on the inserted entities. You should use AFTER INSERT, AFTER UPDATE etc triggers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

A trigger executes code on data change. A view is a (let's say) "callable sub-set of data". It is virtually non-existent, *unless* you select from it. It can't contain a trigger, because it *contains* nothing.

So basically you want a trigger on the base table.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you add the trigger to the table with the same condition as the view.

The trigger body should have something like:

```
if (inserted.NUMBER > 5) {
   do something;
}
//do nothing if inserted.NUMBER is not > 5
```

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB 2.x supports both updatable views and trigger-updatable views.

Your view example is updatable by itself. Therefore you can insert / delete / update rows using the view instead of the table. This will not allow rows containing NUMBER <= 5 in inserts and updates.

You can also define triggers on the view. These triggers are defined with INSTEAD OF INSERT, INSTEAD OF UPDATE or INSTEAD OF DELETE. In the body of the trigger, you can check for the values and either throw an exception for invalid input, or insert the row into the base table.

see http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/triggers-chapt.html

Answer (score 0):

For example, you create `person` table, then insert 2 rows into it as shown below.

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO person (id, name) 
VALUES (1, 'John'), (2, 'David');
```

Next, you create `log` table, then you insert the row whose `num` is `0` into `log` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE log (
  num INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO log (num) VALUES (0);
```

Now, you can create `my_func()` trigger function with `RETURNS trigger` and `LANGUAGE plpgsql` which increments `num` by 1 as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS trigger
AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE log SET num = num + 1;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Next, you create `my_v` view as shown below.

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_v AS
  SELECT * FROM person;
```

Now, you can create `my_t` trigger which runs `my_func()` when `UPDATE` or `DELETE` operation is prevented on `my_view` for each row as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_t INSTEAD OF UPDATE OR DELETE ON my_v
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION my_func();
```

*Memos:

- `INSTEAD OF` can prevent operations.
- You can use `INSTEAD OF` only with a view and `FOR EACH ROW` otherwise there is error.
- You cannot specify one or more columns with `UPDATE OF` when using `INSTEAD OF` otherwise there is error.
- You cannot use `TRUNCATE` with `INSTEAD OF` otherwise there is error.
- The trigger with `BEFORE` or `AFTER` and `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` on a view doesn't work. *[My question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77762057/the-trigger-with-before-or-after-and-insert-update-or-delete-on-a-vie) explains it in detail.

Then, you insert a row to `person` table with `my_v`, then `num` is still `0` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# INSERT INTO my_v (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Robert');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
 id |  name
----+--------
  1 | John
  2 | David
  3 | Robert
(3 rows)

postgres=# SELECT num FROM log;
 num
-----
   0
(1 row)
```

Then, you try to update `name` to `Tom` on all 3 rows on `person` table with `my_v`, then the update is prevented, then `num` is `3` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# UPDATE my_v SET name = 'Tom';
UPDATE 0
postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
 id |  name
----+--------
  1 | John
  2 | David
  3 | Robert
(3 rows)

postgres=# SELECT num FROM log;
 num
-----
   3
(1 row)
```

Then, you try to delete 2 rows from `person` table where `id` is `2` and `3` with `my_v`, then the deletion is prevented, then `num` is `5` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# DELETE FROM my_v WHERE id IN (2, 3);
DELETE 0
postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
 id |  name
----+--------
  1 | John
  2 | David
  3 | Robert
(3 rows)

postgres=# SELECT num FROM log;
 num
-----
   5
(1 row)
```