# postgresql "instead of" error

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I had this issue before, but couldnt formulate my question properly.

This is my trigger creation in postgresql

```
  CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
      INSTEAD OF UPDATE
      ON schemename.viewname
      FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE schemename.functioninthisschemename();
```

This thing works if i do it on local test database, but on server it throws me error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSTEAD" LINE 2:   INSTEAD OF UPDATE

Can you please explain me, why i get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this is a versioning issue in Postgres.

Postgres 9.1 supports "instead of" triggers.  See [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html).

Postgres 9.0 and earlier do not support "instead of" triggers.  See [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: looks fair...
how do i make trigger for a view then?

Comment: @AlexanderCapone . . . That functionality is not supported prior to Postgres 9.1.  Here is another question on the subject:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451096/execute-trigger-on-view.