# TRIGGER ON VIEW in PostgreSQL doesn't trigger

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers, sql-view

I'm trying to add a trigger on a `VIEW` in PostgreSQL 9.6.

This is my view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW names AS
SELECT one.name AS name_one, two.name AS name_two, three.name AS name_three
FROM table_one one
LEFT JOIN table_two two ON one.id = two.id
LEFT JOIN table_three three ON two.id = three.id;
```

This is my trigger function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_name_changed() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_notify('name_changed', row_to_json(NEW)::text);
  RETURN NULL;
END; 
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And my `CREATE TRIGGER`:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER notify_name_changed INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "names"
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_name_changed();
```

This doesn't fire any changes whenever something happens in one of the base tables.
However, creating 3 individual triggers does, but is somewhat unrelated to the view:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER notify_name_changed AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "one"
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_name_changed();
    
CREATE TRIGGER notify_name_changed AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "two"
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_name_changed();
    
CREATE TRIGGER notify_name_changed AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "three"
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_name_changed();
```

Isn't it possible to add a trigger directly on a view, which fires in the event of any changes in base tables used in that view?

Comment: An `instead of` trigger fires, when you insert into the **view**, not if you insert into one of the base tables

Comment: ...if I `insert` directly into a `view` doesn't that break the relationship between the `view` and `base tables`, and sort of remove the idea of the `view`?

Comment: It's not clear to me in the question - are you actually doing an INSERT on the view when you say the view trigger isn't firing?

Comment: No, I'm doing an `insert` in one of the base tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the concept of a view.

A view does not hold any data, you can see it as a “crystallized SQL statement” that has a name. Whenever a view is used in a query, it is replaced by its definition in the “query rewrite” step.

An `INSTEAD OF` trigger for `UPDATE` on a view is triggered only if you update *the view itself*, not the underlying tables. For that, you'd have to define triggers on those tables.

The point that you are probably missing is that if something changes in the underlying tables, it is immediately changed in the view, since the view is just a query on the base table.

Comment: I agree, and it make sense. My goal was to be able to ´listen` (sort of) on the `view`, for any changes made in its base tables. Instead of on each individual base table, as this makes it more difficult to automatic find the changes it makes in the `view`, which is what I need.

Comment: The view never changes - it has no content.

Comment: Make sense, yes. Thank you.

Comment: I think it should be supported: 

_On views, triggers can be defined to execute instead of INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations. Such INSTEAD OF triggers are fired once for each row that needs to be modified in the view._

See [Overview of Trigger Behavior](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html)

Comment: @SergiuIndrie Sure, but I don't get your point. This doesn't say that a trigger on a view fires when the underlying tables are changed.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger with a view is fired when `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` operation is prevented on a view but not on the base table of the view. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451096/execute-a-trigger-on-a-view-in-postgresql/77815577#77815577) explains the trigger with a view in detail.

*Memos:

- `INSTEAD OF` can prevent operations.
- You can use `INSTEAD OF` only with a view and `FOR EACH ROW` otherwise there is error.
- You cannot specify one or more columns with `UPDATE OF` when using `INSTEAD OF` otherwise there is error.
- You cannot use `TRUNCATE` with `INSTEAD OF` otherwise there is error.
- The trigger with `BEFORE` or `AFTER` and `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` on a view doesn't work. *[My question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77762057/the-trigger-with-before-or-after-and-insert-update-or-delete-on-a-vie) explains it in detail.