# The trigger with `BEFORE` or `AFTER` and `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` on a view doesn't work in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-view, postgresql-triggers

I created, as shown below:

- A `table` called `person`
- A `table` called `log`, with 1 row inserted in it.
- A `view` called `my_v`
- A `trigger function` called `my_func()`, whose purpose is to increment `num.log` by `1`.
- A `trigger` called `my_t`, that executes `my_func()` `before` `each statement` (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`) on `my_v`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  name VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE log (
  num INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO log (num) VALUES (0);

CREATE VIEW my_v AS
  SELECT * FROM person;

CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS trigger
AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE log SET num = num + 1;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER my_t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON my_v
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION my_func();
```

For good measure, I also tested when the `trigger` `my_t` executes `after` `each statement`

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_t AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON my_v
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION my_func();
```

With this setup, the value of `num`  in table `log` is expected to count how many times `my_func()` was invoked by the trigger.

When inserting, updating or deleting a row into/from `my_v`, `log.num` remains at `0`. See below the statements, the last one of which is the check from table `log` (*actually tested after each action but removed from here in order to shorten the question*):

```sql
postgres=# INSERT INTO my_v (name) VALUES ('John');
INSERT 0 1 /* -> 1 row successfully inserted */

postgres=# UPDATE my_v SET name = 'Tom';
UPDATE 1 /* -> 1 row successfully updated */

postgres=# DELETE FROM my_v;
DELETE 1 /* -> 1 row successfully deleted */

postgres=# SELECT num FROM log;
 num
-----
   0
(1 row)
```

So, the trigger with `BEFORE` or `AFTER` and `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` on a view doesn't work in PostgreSQL.

**Important**: an alternative version of the `my_t` trigger with `INSTEAD OF` and `FOR EACH ROW` does work properly:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_t INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON my_v
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION my_func();
```

How can I create `my_t` trigger which triggers `my_func()` before or after `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` operation happens on `my_v` for each statement?

Comment: I have found your question very long and difficult to read, and edited it. Your SQL statements are simple/short enough that people on this site do not need a detailed description of every single one of them, the code speaks for itself +  a single block of code makes it easier for everyone to copy from and test for themselves. Please check it matches what you described before.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I reproduced the issue on **Postgres16**: DDL queries are executed successfully and without any warning but the DML does not fire the trigger (I added a `NOTICE` to be extra sure it doesn't). According to the documentation, it should have worked since at least v9.4, possibly v9.1. When I put the trigger on the table rather than the view, it works as expected, which would mean the issue is not with the trigger itself nor with the function... Either there is a bug or I am missing something obvious (and my postgres server too since it does not complain about the DDL).

Comment: "Statement-level triggers on a view are fired only if the action on the view is handled by a row-level INSTEAD OF trigger... Similarly, if the view is automatically updatable, then the action is handled by automatically rewriting the statement into an action on the view's base table, so that the base table's statement-level triggers are the ones that are fired."

Comment: (From the same `CREATE TRIGGER` documentation page already linked elsewhere)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: it could be the explanation but I cannot say I truly understand what this sentence means. I would expect views not to be listed in the description if, all in all, we were forced to define triggers on the underlying table. Could you perhaps give a more complete explanation as an answer?

Comment: @Atmo - *If* you have a row-level INSTEAD OF trigger defined on the view, *then* the statement level triggers on the view will also fire. So in that sense (and only that sense) they do work.

Comment: OK .... however then the triggers work but the `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements won't have any effect, is that correct? If that was the intended behavior, that looks weird.

Comment: The INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE  statements work, just on the base relation not the view. The view will still see the result of those actions and if you want the trigger to do something  they need to be defined on the base relation.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, although not obvious it is documented. BEFORE / AFTER triggers on *Views* is only supported for those views that have an INSTEAD OF trigger.

> **[CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)**
> *(one of the final paragraphs before Examples)*
> Statement-level triggers on a view are fired only if the action on the view is handled by a row-level INSTEAD OF trigger. If the action is handled by an INSTEAD rule, then whatever statements are emitted by the rule are executed in place of the original statement naming the view, so that the triggers that will be fired are those on tables named in the replacement statements. Similarly, if the view is automatically updatable, then the action is handled by automatically rewriting the statement into an action on the view's base table, so that the base table's statement-level triggers are the ones that are fired.

> Kudos to [@Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) for identifying this reference

We can demonstrate this working in a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/Ki2fBnAKC4rH1kMs66UaT/0

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  name VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE log (
  BeforeViewCounter INTEGER,
  InsteadOfViewCounter INTEGER,
  BeforeTableCounter INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO log (BeforeViewCounter, InsteadOfViewCounter, BeforeTableCounter) VALUES (0,0,0);

CREATE VIEW my_v AS
  SELECT * FROM person;

CREATE FUNCTION beforeView_func() RETURNS trigger AS 
'
BEGIN
  UPDATE log SET BeforeViewCounter = BeforeViewCounter + 1;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
' 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION insteadView_func() RETURNS trigger AS 
'
BEGIN
  UPDATE log SET InsteadOfViewCounter= InsteadOfViewCounter + 1;
  
  IF (TG_OP = ''DELETE'') THEN
    DELETE FROM person WHERE name = OLD.name; 
    IF NOT FOUND THEN RETURN NULL; END IF;
    RETURN OLD;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = ''UPDATE'') THEN
    UPDATE person SET name = NEW.name WHERE name = OLD.name;
    RETURN NEW;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = ''INSERT'') THEN
    INSERT INTO person SELECT NEW.*;
    RETURN NEW;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL; 
END;
' 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION beforeTable_func() RETURNS trigger AS 
'
BEGIN
  UPDATE log SET BeforeTableCounter= BeforeTableCounter + 1;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
' 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER before_t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON my_v
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION beforeView_func();

CREATE TRIGGER beforeTable_t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON person
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION beforeTable_func();


CREATE TRIGGER intead_t INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON my_v
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION insteadView_func();



INSERT INTO my_v (name) VALUES ('John');
SELECT * FROM log FULL OUTER JOIN my_v ON 1=1;
UPDATE my_v SET name = 'Tom';
SELECT * FROM log FULL OUTER JOIN my_v ON 1=1;
DELETE FROM my_v;
SELECT * FROM log FULL OUTER JOIN my_v ON 1=1;
```

*There is a flaw in the delete handler, name should be `null` in the end but its not important to this demo.*

| beforeviewcounter | insteadofviewcounter | beforetablecounter | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | Tom |

If you run the same test, this time with the INSTEAD OF trigger removed https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jE6tbJAGTGRqpYKgXW346n/1 then only the trigger on the table fires

| beforeviewcounter | insteadofviewcounter | beforetablecounter | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 3 | `null` |

Although this looks like a strange implementation, the purpose behind this is to extend the support for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE against complex views that can only be defined in INSTEAD OF triggers. The subsystem will call a statement level BEFORE trigger once, *before* executing the INSTEAD OF trigger for each ROW. At the end of the operation the AFTER statement trigger will be called.

Other RDBMS do not generally support triggers on views. This was not designed to allow `BEFORE`/`AFTER` on any arbitrary view but specifically to execute pre-conditions that can prevent the INSTEAD OF ROW statements from executing at all but also because the order of the ROW operations is indeterminate so it allows an extensibility site to assist you to audit or trace the entire batch instead of you trying to engineer solutions that try to track the difference between first/last ROW inside the FOR EACH ROW.